# Animation getTexture() does not exist?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

so I am following Chapter 2 inside "Beginning Java Game Development with Libgdx" by Lee Stemkoski and everything was going well until I got to page 49 "image-based animations"

for some reason two lines of his code give me errors

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;

public class AnimatedActor extends BaseActor
{
public float elapsedTime;
public Animation anim;

public AnimatedActor()
{
    super();
    elapsedTime = 0;
}

public void setAnimation(Animation a)
{ 
    Texture t = a.getKeyFrame(0).getTexture();
    setTexture( t );
    anim = a;
}

public void act(float dt)
{
    super.act( dt );
    elapsedTime += dt;
    if (velocityX != 0 || velocityY != 0)
        setRotation( MathUtils.atan2( velocityY, velocityX ) * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees );
}

public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) 
{
    region.setRegion( anim.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime) );
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
}
}
```

`Texture t = a.getKeyFrame(0).getTexture();`

this line is telling me that getTexture() method cannot be resolved

```
region.setRegion( anim.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime) );
```

this line is just telling me that "cannot resolve method setRegion(Java.lang.object)"

for the second line, I tried to type cast Texture and it does not show any errors, but I can't compile because the first error persists

any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Ok so I found somebody with the same issue en other forums and his problem was fixed and so is mine.

to let people know the answer I'll just leave the link here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140888/animatedactor-class-don%C2%B4t-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From gdx version 1.9.5 `Animation` class is now generic, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4448) for the same. so use in this way :

```
Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
TextureRegion textureRegion;

TextureRegion textureRegion = animation.getKeyFrame(animationTime, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This fix works for gdx version `1.9.10`; android studio `3.4.2`; gradle version `5.4.1`;

```
public class AnimatedActor extends BaseActor
    {
    ...
        public AnimatedActor()
        {
            super();
            elapsedTime = 0;
            anim = null;
        }
        public void setAnimation(Animation a)
        {
            TextureRegion t = (TextureRegion) a.getKeyFrame(0);
            setTexture(t.getTexture());
            anim = a;
        }
    ...
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
        {
            TextureRegion t2 = (TextureRegion) anim.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime);
            region.setRegion(t2.getTexture());
            super.draw(batch,parentAlpha);
        }
    ...
    }
```